# Image type file in __construct()

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to add a default profile picture after someone register using FOSUser Bundle. But, I don't know how to add this kind of file in  my __construct since it is a image mapped entity required.

Here is my User entity :

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="L'image doit être au format jpg")
     * @Assert\File( maxSize = "100k",mimeTypes={ "image/jpg" })
     */
    private $image;

    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
        $this->image = 'http://lorempixel.com/300/300/';
    }
}
```

I tried to adapt : https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

Comment: I don't see any question. Please describe the problem you are having, e.g. Is the default image not persisted in the database or will it not be displayed? What have you tried to locate the issue? Do you have any error messages in your output or logs?

Answer (score 0):

the following line " $this->image = 'http://lorempixel.com/300/300/'; " puts a string in the image field, when the validator tries to validate that field with the " @Assert\File(...) " it fails because he found a string instead of a file

what you need to do is to put a file type into that field like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundatio\File\UploadedFile;

class User extends BaseUser
.....
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->image = new UploadedFile("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/", "defaultImg");
    }
}
```

First parameter is the path to your file, the second is the name of that file, check the Symfony API reference for the UploadedFile class : 
http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

I reccomand that you use the @Assert\Image constraint instead of @Assert\File constraint, it's explained here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Image.html

Comment: Ok, your answer helped me but now i'm getting a new error : >The file "http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" does not exist
500 Internal Server Error - FileNotFoundException

Comment: like it says, file not found, the problem is with your link, i tried opening the link with chrome and i got 404 Not Found, try using a valid link or download the image you want on your server, put it in the web folder and reference it using the php magic constant __DIR__ and work your way up with ../..

Comment: I made it works by using the path with the DIR constant ! Unfortunatly now, I'm getting an error : "The file could not be uploaded." after i try to validate my register form. I don't have a file upload field though, but i'm not supposed to add one since i want my default image to be used when i call the constructor